# Spring Boot session based authentication post login other requests are not getting autheticated

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, authorization, spring-session

I am trying to create a spring boot app which will expose a set of apis. Initially there will be a call to an authentication api, which sets a session cookie and then subsequent requests will send that cookie for authentication.

What is happening is during the authentication api call, the flow is working fine and session is getting set in cookie and being saved in redis. Call to the authentication api the second time with the previous cookie even does-not create a new session, but when I try to hit any other api the authentication does not work.

This is my code

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                    authorize
                            .requestMatchers("/v1/login/**").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            ).authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    return http.build();
}



CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

public CustomAuthenticationProvider() {
    super();
}

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    String creds = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    Authentication token;
    if ("VALID".equals(creds)) {
        token = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.authenticated(new User("AuthUser"),
                authentication.getCredentials(), List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
    } else {
        token = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(null, null);
    }
    return token;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return true;
}
```

In the controller I am doing

```
@GetMapping("/{userId}")
public ResponseEntity<UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken>
authenticateUser(@PathVariable("userId") String userId, HttpSession  session) {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(null, userId);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authPrincipal =
            (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken);


    if (authPrincipal.isAuthenticated()) {
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(authPrincipal, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(authPrincipal, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

}
```

My pom.xml contains and Java version is 17

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```